# So changed Git's default editor, now how do i invoke it from Git bash?

Tags: git, editor, default

I've changed Git's default editor by applying the following to Git's global config:

```
core.editor='C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

Now, how do I simply invoke the "default editor" without initiating a commit ? I'm trying to test the settings/change I made.

Thanks!

Using Git version 1.8.1

Comment: Make a commit, then cancel it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run

```
git config -e
```

To edit the configuration in the default editor.