# Invoke git's configured text editor on a temporary file

Tags: bash, git, configuration

I'm scripting out a set of commands for git, and in typical git fashion, I'd like to launch the editor for the user to review and edit a file as input. (This is the style used for commit messages and for interactive rebase.) I can invoke the editor explicitly:

```
vim /tmp/myfile
```

But this ignores the user's settings. I could attempt to read the configuration from `git config`:

```
editor=$(git config core.editor)
$editor /tmp/myfile
```

But this won't work if there isn't an explicit setting for `core.editor` anywhere. `$editor` would just be the empty string in that case.

How can I invoke the user's editor?

Note: I am *not* looking to [edit the configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16451669/1394393).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170724/1256452

Comment: @phd Thanks. I went ahead and accepted your dupe vote, but I'm going to argue this is the [good kind](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) of duplicate. That question never turned up in any of my searching.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git var`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var):

```
editor=$(git var GIT_EDITOR)
$editor /tmp/myfile
```

or simply

```
$(git var GIT_EDITOR) /tmp/myfile
```

This will compute the same value `commit` and `rebase` use for the editor. In addition to git's default (`vi` currently) and the various configuration files, this will also consider the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, which can be used to override other settings within a single process.